# Can I run games that I normally run on ultra settings on Windows 7?

Tags: games

I know this maybe had been asked a lot in the past but the thing is that I want to know if I can run games smoothly such as Skyrim, COD: Black Ops, Prototype 2, FIFA 12, etc using the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 of course.

I'm doing this because Linux always drag my attention but I never tried because of what people said about its performance, so what do you guys think?

My pc specs are:

- Intel Core i7 870
- 8 GB DDR3 RAM
- ATI HD 5750
- Motherboard Intel Extreme Series DP55KG

Comment: Await the steam client.

Answer (score 5):

It's performance is quite good, often edging above Windows, but compatibility may be an issue. You can install [Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) [image: Install Wine] or [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com) to run Windows games on Linux for games that do not have a Linux version. However, some games will not run well or won't run at all oner some settings due to compatibility. You can [search the Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) to check compatibility of your game. Here are some common ratings:

- Garbage: Does not run or runs like rubbish.
- Bronze: Runs partially or needs a workaround
- Silver: Runs well or needs a mild workaround.
- Gold: Runs very well, almost at or equalling Windows
- Platinum: Runs perfectly, possible better than Windows.

Note that "better" does not talk about performance, but compatibility and reliability.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response! I think I'll partition my hard drive and install linux to see how it is.

Comment: @Angel If this answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark to the left.